# Apache allows too big files to be send to the server (in contradiction to configuration)

Tags: php, file-upload, apache2

I implemented Ajax file upload via POST to my json-API written using PHP7/Apache2.

The settings for file upload on the server are:

```
upload_max_filesize = "50M"
post_max_size = "50M"
```

I works in that way that users can indeed not upload files over 50M. However, they can still send multiple Gigabyte sized files to the server and the server will

```
a) try to allocate that much disk space to place the file in the /tmp folder
```

AND

```
b) try to allocate that much memory during file upload
```

Is it possible to have Apache just cancel the file upload if it exceeds the respective limits? (50M)

Comment: Remove the double quotes and also add some memory limit `memory_limit = 512M`

Comment: I tried and using "" VS. not using "" and it makes no difference. The server still tries to place the multi gig file into /tmp and eventually runs out of memory. I also cannot change "memory_limit" because configuration is directory based and would affect the whole application. (Settings are placed in .user.ini under Web/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this without coding it into the website software itself would be to use the `LimitRequestBody` directive in the site’s Apache configuration file.

For example, if your website has all uploads going to `/var/www/uploads`, you could add this to your configuration file:

```
<Directory "/var/www/uploads">
    LimitRequestBody 52428800
</Directory>
```

This would limit uploads to 52428800 bytes, which is 50MB.

Remember to reload/restart Apache after modifying the config file, otherwise this rule will not be applied until the next server reboot.